# need assistance with singly linked list

Tags: c

I need some help with a singly linked list. I am trying to insert a new node for each word read in from my text file and compares it to the words in a dictionary file.From there, the new node is inserted into a hashtable.I feel that I am close(maybe wistful thinking),but I keep getting a segmentation error everytime I run my program. From the looks of my code, does anyone have any idea on what maybe wrong?

```
typedef struct Node {    

 char word[LENGTH+1];  

 struct Node *Next;    
 } Node;

hash_table_t  *create_hash_table(int size)
hashtable = malloc(sizeof(hash_table_t));

if (hashtable == NULL) 
{

return NULL;

}

 hashtable->table= malloc(size* sizeof(struct Node *) )  ;

if (hashtable->table== NULL)
{
  return NULL;
}
for(int i=0; i<size; i++) 
{ 
  hashtable->table[i]=NULL;
  hashtable->size =size;

}
 return hashtable;



typedef struct hash_table_t{
    int size;       /* the size of the table */
  struct  Node **table; /* the table elements */
} hash_table_t;

File *inptr;    

Node* TempNode=NULL;    
Node* new_node=NULL;
Node* Head=NULL;

char buffer[46];

unsigned int hashval;

int j=0;
int count=0;    
int update_counter=0;

inptr= fopen(dictionary, "r"); 

if (inptr == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not open dictionary file");
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
} 

int ch = fgetc(inptr);   
for ( ;; )     
{        
    if ( ch == EOF )    //determines how many words are in the file        
    {           
        break;                
    }        
    if (isalpha(ch) || isdigit(ch) || ispunct(ch))        
    {           
        update_counter = 1;          
    }         
    if (isspace(ch) && update_counter )      
    {           
        count++;           
        update_counter = 0;       
    }     
}
if (update_counter) 
{
    count++;
} 

sizeOfDictionary=count;
rewind(inptr);

hashtable=create_hash_table(sizeOfDictionary);

while(fread(buffer,sizeof(buffer),1,inptr)!=0)
{        
    if(Head==NULL)
    {
        hashval = hash(buffer);
        Head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        strcpy(&Head->word[j],buffer); 
        Head->Next = hashtable->table[hashval];

        hashtable->table[hashval]=Head;
        Head=Head->Next;

        TempNode =  Head; 
    }
    else if(Head!=NULL)
    {
        new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        hashval = hash(buffer);
        strcpy(&new_node->word[j],buffer);
        new_node->Next = hashtable->table[hashval];
        hashtable->table[hashval]=new_node;
        TempNode=new_node->Next;        
    } 
}
return true;
```

Comment: Where exactly do you get the segfault?

Comment: I get it right after the TempNode=new_node->next

Comment: can you give the definition of `Node`?

Comment: yes. here it is: typedef struct Node {    

     char word[LENGTH+1];  

     struct Node *Next;    

 }
 Node;

Comment: @user2014904, `strcpy(&new_node->word[j],buffer);` looks suspicious. What is the length of the string in buffer? what is `LENGTH`?

Comment: As this is homework it would be unfair for your education to fix it. But compile the code with the `-g` flag. Then use `gdb`. (or the moral equivalent for you computing environment). From the code you have posted there is a lot of potential.

Comment: maybe its my hash function thats causing issues...

Comment: How is `hashtable` initialized?

Comment: Also, are you trying to create a circular linked-list?

Comment: no..no circular linked list...just a regular linked list...

Comment: Okay then, what does `hashtable->table[hashval]` contain generally?

Comment: Its a hashtable that contains a pointer to a pointer. so the hashval is calculated and then the new node is inserted based on the hash value.

Comment: I just put in the hash table I created

Comment: When you get segfault, especially repeatable segfault, first reaction should always be: use debugger to get stack trace and see if it was because of NULL pointer. If not that, check all involved pointers and array indexes, that they are initialized. 90% of time, these will be the reason for segfault. Then try running valgrind. If still no clue, proceed with debugging (debug prints, stepping under debugger, reviewing code) and SO questions etc.

Comment: `malloc()` returns (void*) you need to typecast it like this `new_node =(Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));` the same goes for `Head =(Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));`

Comment: @DuniyaHilaDalunga This is C, cast not needed, and common convention is to not do it, it just clutters code.

Comment: @DuniyaHilaDalunga, Read [this](http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html).

Comment: ok, I ran gdb, and here is the output it gave me:
int_malloc (av=av@entry=0xb7fcc420, bytes=bytes@entry=52) at malloc.c:3884
3884       set_head(remainder, remainder_size | PREV_INUSE);

Is it safe to say this is a memory issue with malloc?

Comment: @user2014904, Are you intentionally creating a linked list where every alternate node has words from your text file and every other alternate node has your hashtable values?

Comment: maybe lol..I need to see a diagram on what you are talking about...Im a visual person...

Comment: I think that is correct anish..why, what are you getting at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to explain what is happening in steps:

- `Head = malloc(sizeof(Node));`

  `strcpy(&Head->word[j],buffer);`

---

```
    Head
 ----------
|          |
|  buffer  |
|          |
 ----------
```

---

- `Head->Next = hashtable->table[hashval];`

  `Head=Head->Next;`

  `TempNode =  Head;`

---

```
                         TempNode
                           Head
 ----------          -----------------
|          |  Next  |                 |
|  buffer  | -----> |  table[hashval] |
|          |        |                 |
 ----------          -----------------
     ^
 This is now
 lost forever
```

---

- `new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));`

  `strcpy(&new_node->word[j],buffer);`

  `new_node->Next = hashtable->table[hashval];`

  `TempNode=new_node->Next;`

---

```
                           Head                   new_node               TempNode
 ----------          -----------------           ----------          ----------------- 
|          |  Next  |                 |         |          |  Next  |                 | 
|  buffer  | -----> |  table[hashval] | No link |  buffer  | -----> |  table[hashval] |
|          |        |                 |  here!  |          |        |                 |
 ----------          -----------------           ----------          -----------------
     ^
 This is now
 lost forever
```

---

And so on.

I suspect that the "No link here!" part in my diagram above is causing your segfault. I also do not know how you intend to use your `table[hashval]`, but here goes anyway. This solution just bridges the gaps in your linked list.

**Solution:**

Replace your `while` loop with this:

```
TempNode = Head = NULL;

while(fread(buffer,sizeof(buffer),1,inptr)!=0)
{        
    if(Head==NULL)
    {
        hashval = hash(buffer);
        Head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        strcpy(&Head->word[j],buffer); 
        Head->Next = hashtable->table[hashval];
        Head->Next->Next = NULL;

        TempNode = hashtable->table[hashval] = Head;
    }
    else
    {
        new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        hashval = hash(buffer);
        strcpy(&new_node->word[j],buffer);
        new_node->Next = hashtable->table[hashval];
        hashtable->table[hashval]=new_node;
        new_node->Next->Next = NULL;
        TempNode->Next = new_node;        
        TempNode = new_node;
    } 
    TempNode = TempNode->Next;
}
```

Visually the differences are:

- `Head = malloc(sizeof(Node));`

  `strcpy(&Head->word[j],buffer);`

  `Head->Next = hashtable->table[hashval];`

  `Head->Next->Next = NULL;`

  `TempNode = hashtable->table[hashval] = Head;`

---

```
  TempNode
    Head                  
 ----------          -----------------
|          |  Next  |                 |  Next
|  buffer  | -----> |  table[hashval] | -----> NULL
|          |        |                 |
 ----------          -----------------
```

---

- `TempNode = TempNode->Next`

---

```
    Head                 TempNode                  
 ----------          -----------------
|          |  Next  |                 |  Next
|  buffer  | -----> |  table[hashval] | -----> NULL
|          |        |                 |
 ----------          -----------------
```

---

- `new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));`

  `strcpy(&new_node->word[j],buffer);`

  `new_node->Next = hashtable->table[hashval];`

  `new_node->Next->Next = NULL;`

---

```
    Head                 TempNode                 new_node               
 ----------          -----------------           ----------          ----------------- 
|          |  Next  |                 |         |          |  Next  |                 | 
|  buffer  | -----> |  table[hashval] | No link |  buffer  | -----> |  table[hashval] | ----> NULL
|          |        |                 |  here!  |          |        |                 |
 ----------          -----------------           ----------          -----------------
```

---

- `TempNode->Next = new_node;`

---

```
    Head                 TempNode                new_node               
 ----------          -----------------          ----------          ----------------- 
|          |  Next  |                 |  Next  |          |  Next  |                 | 
|  buffer  | -----> |  table[hashval] | -----> |  buffer  | -----> |  table[hashval] | ----> NULL
|          |        |                 |        |          |        |                 |
 ----------          -----------------          ----------          -----------------
```

---

- `TempNode = new_node;`

---

```
                                                 TempNode
    Head                                         new_node               
 ----------          -----------------          ----------          ----------------- 
|          |  Next  |                 |  Next  |          |  Next  |                 | 
|  buffer  | -----> |  table[hashval] | -----> |  buffer  | -----> |  table[hashval] | ----> NULL
|          |        |                 |        |          |        |                 |
 ----------          -----------------          ----------          -----------------
```

---

And so on.

**Tips:**

- Free whatever memory you have `malloc`ed at the end.
- Do not move your `Head` pointer (unless you need to delete the first element or for some other reason).

Comment: No problem :). Oh I corrected a mistake in my answer in my edited `while` loop. If you think this solved your problem, please click on the check mark next to the answer :)